# Adobe Reader - What is the shortcut to enter the zoom level?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-reader

- Win 7 64 bit
- Adobe Reader XI

Official shortcut list by Adobe: http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/keyboard-shortcuts.html

By accident (read: I really pushed several buttons just to try things out as I had not found the link above yet) I activated a little pop-up windows yesterday where I could enter the exact zoom level. :( Now I can't seem to find it again. Does anyone know which shortcut that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **Ctrl + Y** on my german keyboard so maybe it would be **Ctrl + Z** on american, try both of them.

Comment: Ha! I knew it! IT IS NOT ON THE LIST. HOW CAN IT NOT BE ON THE LIST!!1111eleven

Answer (score 1):

Zoom commands are located in the Menu View.

Ctrl + Y = Zoom To (then you get the magnification choices)